# How to change fixed line height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to change the line height of a specific item in a theme. It seems that this item has a fixed minimum line height, which I can't get around.

On https://aerycs.cocoto.eu if you put something into the basket an open the preview (top right corner, green link) theres a red title of the item.

I am not able to find out how to make the line height smaller.

You can see a sample image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGe6R.jpg

Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change CSS

```
.basket-item-container .basket-item .meta-container-wrapper .meta-container-wrapper-inner .meta-container .item-name {
    font-weight: 650;
    font-size: 95%;
    line-height: 1.2;/*Add This*/
    display: block;/*Add This*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood this correctly, we are looking at this section of markup:

```
<div class="meta-container">
<div>
<a href="/55-55-c-aero-wt-tour-testsieger-20-24-speichen-carbon-laufradsatz-clincher-wickel-technologie-tubeless-kompatibel-bis-110kg_2505_11402" class="item-name text-primary text-appearance">C 55/55 C AERO-WT - TOUR TESTSIEGER - Carbon Laufradsatz, Clincher, Wickel Technologie, tubeless kompatibel, bis 110kg</a>
```

In which case, something like:

```
.meta-container .item-name.text-primary.text-appearance {
line-height: 36px;
}
```

will target the text and apply a new line-height.